# Animations around ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im trying to figure out how to have an animation, then load ajax, then have another animation in order. I have so far;

```
$('.photography-folio').click(function(){
    $( "#left-main" ).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500 );
    $( "#home-background-left" ).animate({ width: "0%" }, 1000 );
    $('#left-main').load( "http://localhost:8888/harperwhite/photography.html #folio-block" );
    $( "#home-background-left" ).animate({ width: "50%" }, 1000 );
    $( "#left-main" ).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500 );
});
```

So I would like to fade out the div that will have the contents changed via ajax, then animate the width of #home-background-left, then load the new content with ajax (but kept hidden) , animate the #home-background-left back in then fade up the new ajax content.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

try the setTimeout Function

```
    $('.photography-folio').click(function(){
        $( "#left-main" ).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500 );
        $( "#home-background-left" ).animate({ width: "0%" }, 1000 );
       setTimeout(function(){$('#left-main').load( "http://localhost:8888/harperwhite/photography.html #folio-block",function(){
 $( "#home-background-left" ).animate({ width: "50%" }, 1000 );
        $( "#left-main" ).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500 );
})},estimatedTimeToCompleteAnimations);
    });
```

Since AJax gonna be async you want to make sure the animation does get completed before ajax call thats why you should use setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Try calling ajax in `animation` callback function of starting animation, and then ending animations in `load` callback function after request is finished.

You can read more about *callback* parameters on jQuery documentation pages of desired methods:

- [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete)
- [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete)

Here is an example code with comments how you can achieve this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Animation before ajax request, the third parameter is an callback function
  // that starts ajax request after animation finishes
  $('#somethingAnimated').animate({
    width: 0
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).load(
      'http://your-url.com',
      null,
      function() {
        // Here is callback function after ajax request finishes with end animation
        $(this).animate({
          width: 200
        }).text('test');
      }
    );
  });

});
```

```css
#somethingAnimated {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="somethingAnimated">
</div>
```

With code from your question it can be used like this:

```
$('.photography-folio').click(function() {
    $( "#left-main" ).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500 );
    $( "#home-background-left" ).animate({ width: "0%" }, 1000 , 
        function() {
          $('#left-main').load( 
            "http://localhost:8888/harperwhite/photography.html#folio-block", 
            null, 
            function() {
                $( "#home-background-left" ).animate({ width: "50%" }, 1000 );
                $( "#left-main" ).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500 );
            }
        );
    });
});
```